# How to Disambiguate Names and Type-Identifiers in `typealias`?

Tags: xcode, swift

For example in this *pseudo* Swift-like code, the ident `Name` should be ambiguous. I'v suffixed the names with a number of `´` in order to show which one means which.

```
struct Name´ {}

protocol SomeType {
    typealias Name´´: OtherType
}

class Some<Name´´´: OtherType>: SomeType {
    typealias Name´´ = Name´´´
}
```

Comment: Honestly, why would you want to do that? Just rename the generic placeholder: `class Some<N: OtherType>: SomeType { typealias Name = N }`.

Comment: Because names should be descriptive and look pretty. If there's also a convention how you should name type parameters, e.g. `SessionDelegateT: SessionDelegateType` it may conflict with the conforming protocol's  type alias name. However, in my example I actually can use `Name` as type parameter name and it won't conflict with the struct's name. So, it's not as bad as it looks - just Xcode, again, confused me with wrong syntax coloring and bogus symbol lookup and wrong issues markers.

Comment: The only problem – as far as I can see – is that in `typealias Name´´ = Name´´´` you cannot use the same name on both sides. Replacing one by `N` was just an example.

Comment: Exactly, the Swift compiler will issue an error. It should not, IMHO. That is, `typealias Name = Name` should be legal, where alias name refers to the type of the conforming protocol, and the type-id is the nearest type in scope  - which is the type parameter of the generic in this case.

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer for that, currently it seems impossible. – But note that you don't need the typealias in the class definition at all if the type can be inferred, e.g. if there is a `func foo(n : Name)` function in the protocol (and the class).